# react How to make onClick not work only on certain elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

development environment
react.js
typescript
next.js

I don't want to trigger the onClick process when the span tag is pressed.
How should I implement it?

```
 return (
    <div className="padding-16 flex gap-5 flex-container" onClick={onClickUser}>
        <img src={img} />
      <div className="flex flex-direction gridgap-5">
        <p>
          {name}
        </p>
        <p>
          {age}
        </p>
      </div>
      <span className="hover" onClick={isShowCard}>
        <img src="img/dot.svg" />
      </span>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation()` for `span` click event.

```js
 isShowCard = (event) => {
     event.stopPropagation()
     ...
 }
 return (
    <div className="padding-16 flex gap-5 flex-container" onClick={onClickUser}>
        <img src={img} />
      <div className="flex flex-direction gridgap-5">
        <p>
          {name}
        </p>
        <p>
          {age}
        </p>
      </div>
      <span className="hover" onClick={isShowCard}>
        <img src="img/dot.svg" />
      </span>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: What if I already have onclick defined in the span tag?

Comment: <span className="hover" onClick={isShowCard}>
        <img src="img/dot.svg" />
      </span>

Answer (score 0):

Have `onClickUser` check to see whether it has an ancestor with a class name of `hover` before continuing. For example, change:

```
const onClickUser = (e) => {
  // code
};
```

to

```
const onClickUser = (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('.hover')) {
    // do nothing
    return;
  }
  // code
};
```

Comment: It will not make any difference at all, since this code is only modifying the parent handler. The code in the answer will work regardless.